# Cannot use component in function

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus

Assignment:

> Write a package declaration that declares:
>   1) (25 Pts) User defined type for BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) for 4 digit decimal numbers (In BCD notation four bits are used to indicate a decimal digit. Hence, the two digit decimal number 23 is given by “00100011”.).
>   2) (25 Pts) An overloaded function “+” that adds two numbers specified in the BCD notation and returns the sum in the BCD notation.
>   3) (20 Pts) A function that tests whether an integer is odd or not.
>   4) (30 Pts) Write a package body that contains the function body for the previous questions
>   5) Simulate your design

I tried implement "+" operator overload for bcd numbers in vhdl and I used components for this job.

but I cannot instantiate components into overload function:

```
package bcd_package is

subtype bcd_unit IS std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
type bcd_number IS array (3 DOWNTO 0) of bcd_unit;

FUNCTION "+" (a, b : bcd_number) RETURN bcd_number; 

  component BCD_Adder is  
  port( 
     X : in bcd_unit;
     Y : in bcd_unit;
     Cin : in std_logic;
     S : out bcd_unit;
     Cout : out std_logic 
  );
  end component; 
end bcd_package;
```

My package body :

```
package body bcd_package is

FUNCTION "+" (X, Y : bcd_number) RETURN bcd_number IS  
  variable C1, C2, C3, C4: std_logic;
  variable S : bcd_number;
BEGIN
   G_FA0: work.BCD_Adder port map(X(0), Y(0), '0', S(0), C1); <- problem
   ...
   RETURN S;
END "+";
end bcd_package;
```

and when i compile , my code get this error :
[My error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPoPl.png)

> Error  (10500): VHDL syntax error at bcd_backage.vhdl(70) near text "port";  expecting "*", or "'", or "."
>   Error  (10500): VHDL syntax error at bcd_backage.vhdl(70) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="

Comment: A component instantiation is a concurrent statement, while a subprogram function body is comprised of sequential statements. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 11. Concurrent statements, 11.7 Component instantiation statements, 11.7.3 Instantiation of a design entity, 4.3 Subprogram body and 10. Sequential statements.You're trying to include a structural description comprised of an external block in the place a behavioral description comprised of a sequence of statements should be, hence syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you, You have any idea ?

Comment: Any idea? That's not a specific question. Besides lacking a sufficient understanding of VHDL the concept of a BCD digit (subtype bcd_number) adder appears flawed. What happens when you add "0101" (5) to itself? The result should be "0001", "0000" (10). Where BCD arithmetic is actually found (e.g. calculators) it's [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) dealing with arrays of BCD digits. Also see [Introduction to VHDL - Steven J. Merrifield](http://www.stevenmerrifield.com/papers/vhdl_notes.pdf). Is this a school assignment?

Comment: yes , its boring my university final practice ! and i should do it [ implement '+' overload for bcd numbers and some other functions and package all functions+types] :((

Comment: Write a package declaration that declares:
1) (25 Pts) User defined type for BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) for 4 digit decimal numbers (In BCD notation
four bits are used to indicate a decimal digit. Hence, the two digit decimal number 23 is given by
“00100011”.).
2) (25 Pts) An overloaded function “+” that adds two numbers specified in the BCD notation and returns the
sum in the BCD notation.
3) (20 Pts) A function that tests whether an integer is odd or not.
4) (30 Pts) Write a package body that contains the function body for the previous questions
5) Simulate your design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL Error Code 10500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968647/vhdl-error-code-10500)

Comment: Notice `1) (25 Pts) User defined type for BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) for 4 digit decimal numbers (In BCD notation four bits are used to indicate a decimal digit. Hence, the two digit decimal number 23 is given by “00100011”.)`. Your single digit BCD adder function doesn't deal with 4 digit decimal numbers (easier than arbitrary length at least).

Comment: Also see IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.5 Subprogram overloading and 4.5.2 Operator overloading. An example of an overloaded "+" operator can be found in package numeric_std ([IEEE-SA Supplemental Material](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076-2008/) the zip, file ieee/numeric_std-body.vhdl) where you'll find binary arithmetic is done with a loop. It would seem 4 BCD digit arithmetic could be done with a nested loop and a carry between digits. You still need to come up with a type or subtype representing a 4 decimal digit number in BCD.

Comment: Now it is , my code now currectly works with 4 digit decimal number. but i should package it components and write a function for it.

Comment: i read this file -> "ieee/numeric_std-body.vhdl" it write functions like as c language and not used logical components.

Comment: And that says your answers for 1) and 2) are separate and distinguishable. Note the bit about "An overloaded function “+”".

Comment: Owww , Yes you are right saying that ! So i can write overload function like numeric_std ?